# ByBit : API ColdFusion

Tags: api, cryptoapi, coldfusion-2016, bybit

Having trouble with ByBit By/Sell API. ColdFusion any help appreciated.

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/spot/v3/?console#t-authenticationparameters

Authentication for POST
POST
rule: timestamp + api_key + recv_window + raw_request_body

param_str =
"1659073093578T0d98KyVamQ62YBzN85000{
"symbol": "BTCUSDT",
"orderQty":"0.05",
"side": "Sell",
"orderType": "LIMITT",
"timeInForce": "GTC",
"orderPrice": "24500",
"orderLinkId": "spotA0008"
}"

curl --location --request POST 'https://api-testnet.bybit.com/spot/v3/private/order' \

--header 'X-BAPI-API-KEY: {api key}' 
--header 'X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP: 1659067662307' 
--header 'X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW: 5000' 
--header 'X-BAPI-SIGN: cc63fb44be4a87f4b7bbd42db012ddacc1c935c3d3ae3e01c3b4be393522c213' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '{
"symbol": "BTCUSDT",
"orderQty":"0.01",
"side": "Buy",
"orderType": "LIMIT",
"timeInForce": "GTC",
"orderPrice": "21300",
"orderLinkId": "spotx006",
"orderCategory": 1,
"triggerPrice": "21700"
}'

This is the Post Example.
For Account - my signature works fine.

```
   <cfscript>

    apiKey = "#_key#";
    apiSecret = "#_s#";

   newbody = serializeJSON({
      "symbol": "#symb#",
      "orderQty":"#qty#",
       "side": "#side#",
       "orderType": "#type#"
   });

   ts_key_str = #unixdatetimeNow.getTime()# & '#apikey#' & '5000';

   str_to_sign = #unixdatetimeNow.getTime()# & '#apikey#' & '5000' & '#newbody#';

   HMAC = hmac(str_to_sign, apiSecret, "HMACSHA256");

   </cfscript>

    <cfhttp url="#base_api##req_path#" method="POST" result="result" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#newbody#">
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content_Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-SIGN-TYPE" value="2"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-API-KEY" value="#_key#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW" value="5000"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-SIGN" value="#lhmac#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP" value="#unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#"> 
    </cfhttp>
```

Even adding the ts_key_str in front of new body does not work either.

I get bad signature. When getting account data I using this it works fine cfhttpparam type="body" value=""

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Might be a timestamp : #unixdatetimeNow.getTime()# gets me 13 digits, but when use in a cfset it become 15 digits.  How do i restrice to 13 digits?

Comment: 1666807130469  then becomes 166680713046918 in cfset

Comment: IGNORE : the 18 is from start of .  My bad.  No idea why this wont authorize.  Account process works.  Tried almost everything.

Comment: SORTED : was a Timestamp error - slight differences in the string time and http post time : so I just created a timestamp and send same exact times to each.  String Time and Post Time and 5000 is the server time diff which was only 350 with stamp : so well within time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timestamp issue.

Set one timestamp, and use that timestamp.  So it doesn't maybe pull different timestamp on a delayed call.

Updated code.

```
    <!--- MARKET --->
    <cfset b_body = '{"symbol": "#pair#","orderQty":"#size#","side": "#side#","orderType": "MARKET"}'>

    <cfset unixdatetimeNow = dateConvert( "local2Utc", now() )>
    <cfset timestamp = #unixdatetimeNow.getTime()#>

    <cfscript>
        apiKey = "#_key#";
        apiSecret = "#_s#";
        str_to_sign = #timestamp# & '#apikey#' & '5000' & '#b_body#';   
        HMAC = hmac(str_to_sign, apiSecret, "HMACSHA256");
    </cfscript>

    <cfset lhmac = lCase(#hmac#)>
   
    <cfhttp url="#base_api##req_path#" method="POST" result="result" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#b_body#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-SIGN-TYPE" value="2">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-SIGN" value="#lhmac#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-API-KEY" value="#_key#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-TIMESTAMP" value="#timestamp#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-BAPI-RECV-WINDOW" value="5000"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content_Type" value="application/json">
    </cfhttp>
```